# Applying order_by and distinct together

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am applying distinct on a Queryset

```
matches = queryset.filter(name__contains=query).distinct('entity_id')
```

And I wan't to apply `order_by('-count')` as well i.e

```
matches=queryset.filter(name__contains=query).order_by('count').distinct('entity_id')
```

but getting error

```
ProgrammingError at /v1/search/
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("entity"."entity_id") "entity...
```

How to do this.

Comment: Is it required for you to add a field to `distinct()`?

Comment: Yes as 'entity_id' is a foreign key and I wan't to fetch distinct 'entity_id'